# I need an SQL statement to get the minimum value from a column from the rows with specific ID

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I want an SQL statement to get the minimum value from the "Fastest_Lap" column from the rows with specific "Race_ID" in this case "101".

Consider this table:

[Table from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDyNN.png)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `Select min(Fastest_Lap) from TABLE where Race_ID = '101'` where you replace `TABLE` with your table name.
It is hard to tell what the datatype of the Race_ID column is (string vs int) so you might not need the single-quotes around the Race_ID value.
If you are trying to find the quickest lap for every Race_ID you would need to add Race_ID to your select criteria and then do a `group by Race_ID` at the end

Answer (score 0):

As @Steve G points out.

```
select min(Fastest_Lap) from TABLE where Race_ID = '101'
```